# Get meta tags datas from jQuery $.post()

Tags: jquery, post

I have the following code to get some meta tags informations.

```
$(pageDetailsSecond).('head').find('meta[name="description"]').attr("content");
```

I also tried with this one:

```
$(pageDetailsSecond).('meta[name="description"]').attr("content");
```

But it doesn't work.

My original steps are the following:

1. I get the source code of a page with `$.post()`.
2. I get all the source page into `$(pageDetailsSecond)`.
3. I want to get some meta tags.

Comment: What was your intention with `.('head')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this.

```
$pageDetailsSecond = "<html><head><meta name='description' content='bla bla bla'></head></html>";

var no = $($pageDetailsSecond).filter("meta[name='description']").attr("content");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/marioaraque/p6b2c6y2/

Comment: I get an `undefined`. If I make an alert with `pageDetailsSecond` I see the meta tags...

Comment: Bue this variable contains only html? What type of data is it?

Comment: Yes my alert game me full HTML (from <head> to </body>).

Comment: `undefined is not a function`

Comment: Your fiddle is wrong , why do you share a link with js errors? I've edited my answer with the final solution. You have to check your code before share!

Comment: Works. I think I had a cache problem... On local it's works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(pageDetailsSecond).('head').find('meta[name="description"]').attr("content");
//------------------^^^^^^^^^ remove all this!
$(pageDetailsSecond).find('meta[name="description"]').attr("content");
```

Or maybe you wanted this instead:

```
$(pageDetailsSecond).find('head meta[name="description"]').attr("content");
```

Comment: I get an `undefined`. If I make an alert with `pageDetailsSecond` I see the meta tags...

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Lonowski.